# Print the lines of a log file which starts with date format "yyyy-mm-dd" in Python

Tags: python, regex, date

I have a log file. I want to print only the lines of the log file which starts with date in format "yyyy-mm-dd" and ignore all other lines.
Log file looks like below:
"
Process starts

```
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
What were you doing on 20-09-2016
2016-09-20 I was working
log file ends
```

The output should be:

```
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
2016-09-20 I was working
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not a coding service. Please show us what you've tried so we can help you assess where you went wrong.

Comment: I accepted it. May be by mistake. Your answer is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.match`

**Ex:**

```
import re
s = """2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
What were you doing on 20-09-2016
2016-09-20 I was working
log file ends"""

for line in s.splitlines():
    if re.match(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} ", line):    #Check if each line matches condition.
        print(line)
```

**Output:**

```
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
2016-09-20 I was working
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$
```

Python snippet:

```
import re
str = """
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
What were you doing on 20-09-2016
2016-09-20 I was working
log file ends
"""

print(re.findall(r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$",str,re.MULTILINE));
```

*Output*

```
['2018-01-02 This is good', '2017-03-22 This is also good', '2016-09-20 I was working']
```

Comment: Your regex is overly complicated (unless I'm missing something). `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$` should work fine. You don't need a non-matching group (let alone a forward reference group).

Comment: @FHTMitchell You are right, cheers. The construct was indeed redundant here.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of this regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/GwnDbK/2).

```
import re

data = """
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
What were you doing on 20-09-2016
2016-09-20 I was working
log file ends
"""

for line in re.findall(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}.*$', data, flags=re.M):
    print(line)
```

This prints:

```
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
2016-09-20 I was working
```

Comment: Why use `.*?$`? `.*$` will work fine in multi-line mode.

Comment: @FHTMitchell Yeah, It's just reflex :) I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to `fullmatch` each line:

```
for line in lines:
    m = re.fullmatch('^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (.*)$', line)
    if m:
        print(m.group())
```

Output:

```
2018-01-02 This is good
2017-03-22 This is also good
2016-09-20 I was working
```

Comment: This solution does unnecessary capturing.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Figured OP was interested in the substring after the date. I guess I was right.

Comment: What? That's not what you are doing. You are using two capturing groups and not just one.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Mine is the only answer that uses `SRE_Match.group` (or a capture group at all, for that matter). Calling `group()` gives the whole string, `group(0)` is the date, `group(1)` is the rest of the string. I assume OP either knew this or was smart enough to figure it out by the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, but the OP does not mention anything about capturing, so why do it? Capturing is expensive. I would not go as far as to make that assumption.